# What version to use on Dell Insprion 1200?

Tags: installation

I've tried Slacko 5.5 (it works) but I would like something better where I can use more easily the installing of various software and control of browser.

Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 will not load.  I get an error message stating my CPU needs a different Kernel,  I am not highly knowable in programing and thus would like a user friendly OS.

Currently using Windows XP Home.

Comment: If would actually help if you included **exactly** the error you get. I'm guessing you need the PAE kernel?.

Answer (score 0):

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) use the PAE kernel in the i386 versions, at least for version 12.04.